# Send "\u2264" via JSON from Server to js client

Tags: json

I am using `JSON` to send data from my server to my javascript/html5 client.  I use `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` to encode objects and strings on the server side and jquery/ajax to unencode.  This has worked fine until today, when I tried to send an inequality symbol ("less than or equal to") from server to client.  On the client side, I got this error:

message:

> "Unexpected end of input."

When I remove the inequality and re-try, the string goes through fine.  I suppose I could create my own special encoding for the 'or equal to' inequality symbols, but that seems to go against the happy grain of leaving encoding up to the parser.

Interesting to note that I do not have the reverse problem: When I 'stringify' from the js side and send a string with an 'or equal' inequality via ajax/json to the server, there is no problem with unencoding on the server side.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: JSON can handle any legal Unicode character.  But if you use the wrong (non-UTF8) translation between character and byte format somewhere then you corrupt the data.

Comment: What are you using to decode the data? How does the JSON look like? `JSON.parse('"\\u2264"')` works just fine, as does `JSON.parse('"\u2264"')`

Comment: @Felix Is that a static method?  The JSON objects I am using do not appear to have it.  So far, I use JSON in my server-side servlet by instantiating a JSONObject and then calling its put methods.  For example, json.put("expression", "1 + 2 \u2264 5");   I should add that I then call toString on the json instance and use the servlet's PrintWriter to send that String as the server response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "JSON objects". `JSON` is an object, just like `Math` is, and it has a method `.parse`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @Felix I mean on the Server side, where my code is in java.

Comment: Oh, I was just referring to the client side.